# Data service in Reactive Extension

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I want to have a generic class for an in-memory cache of data handling creations, updates and deletions. Underlying model inherits from an interface with an Id of type string.

```
interface IModel
{
  string Id { get; }
}
```

Handling creations & updates is easy. For instance, if I want to subscribe to the stream and populate a Dictionary, I know that a creation is needed if the model Id is not already there, otherwise it is an update.

My question is:
How would you handle deletions **without introducing another class to wrap my models**? I would like to keep an `IObservable<TModel>`, not something like `IObservable<Event<TModel>>` or `IObservable<Pair<string, TModel>>`, but I don't see how. Is that possible?

```
interface IDataService<TModel>
{
  IObservable<TModel> DataStream { get; }
}
```

Comment: You could create nested streams using `IObservable<IObservable<TModel>>` so that any models add/updated on inner streams are deleted when each inner stream ends.

Comment: Sounds interesting, I didn't thought about that. I am not sure how convenient it would be in the usage and how much overhead it would add to the implementation. I will give it a try.

Comment: Are you restricted to only the one stream? Or could you have multiple ones?

Comment: Are you suggesting to create separate streams for each operation? Or at least dedicating one for deletions? Sounds good too!

Comment: First one, so you'd have something like `ItemChanged`, `ItemAdded`, `ItemDeleted`. You could combine the add and changed if you really wanted, but I like the separation of concerns by having them split, saves consumers from having to *always* worry about whether they had seen an item before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Enigmativity suggested you could use nested observable sequences to solve this problem. 
This is touched on in the [Sequences of coincidence](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/17_SequencesOfCoincidence.html) section in IntroToRx.

### How would this work?

You can think of nested sequences to be something like a 2d Array, or even more specifically a [jagged array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array).
The outer sequence is the container for the inner sequences.
The arrival of an inner sequence represents a *creation* of a model.

```
interface IDataService<TModel>
{
    IObservable<IObservable<TModel>> DataStream { get; }
}
```

Once you have an inner sequence all values that it produces are updates (except for the first one). 
An inner sequence will only produce updates for a single id.
When the inner sequence completes, the represent a *deletion*.

This pattern works well for various use-cases, as outlined in the initial paragraph in the link above.

As a marble diagram you would have something like the following. 
Each row represents an inner sequence.

```
m1  1---2----3--|
m2     a----|
m3       x----y---z--
```

This would result in the following logical flow:

1. Create m1 with the state of '1'
2. Create m2 with the state of 'a'
3. Update m1 with value '2'
4. Create m3 with value 'x'
5. Delete m2
6. Update m1 with value '3'
7. Update m3 with value 'y'
8. Delete m1
9. Update m3 with value 'z'

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I had to switch to another topic.
I was wondering how to perfom buffering/windowing when this dataservice stream is bound to an UI? do you have some hints? it seems like IObs<IObs<T>> is not convenient in that case right?

Comment: These are two separate concerns. 1st solve your modelling problem. I have suggested using nested observable sequences to do this. Once you have solved your modelling problem, then you have separate problem of keeping the UI responsive. Break that into in independent query.